# Confirming the triangular inequality for Lévy-metric $d_L(F,G)$ and $d_L(F,G)<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

Let $F,G$ be cumulative distribution functions.
The Lévy-metric is defined to be
$$
d_L(F,G)=\inf\left\{h\geq 0: F(x-h)-h)\leq G(x)\leq F(x+h)+h~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

I would like to confirm that this is indeed a metric.

In particular, two points are not totally clear to me:

**(1) Why is $d_L(F,G)<\infty$?**

My idea is to assume that $d_L(F,G)=\infty$. Then, for all $\varepsilon\geq 0$, there exists some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon > G(x) > F(x+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$ since otherwise the infimum would have been some real $\varepsilon \geq 0$. But $F(x-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon\leq F(x+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$ hence contradiction.

--

The proof of the triangular inequality goes as follows:

Let $d_L(F,G)<\epsilon_1, d_L(G,H)<\epsilon_2$.

Then
$$
F(x-\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)-\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\leq G(x-\epsilon_2)-\epsilon_2\leq H(x)\leq G(x+\epsilon_2)+\epsilon_2\leq F(x+\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)+\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2.
$$ 
Hence $d_L(F,H)\leq \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$.

Taking the infimum over $\epsilon_1$ and taking the infimum over $\epsilon_2$ gives
$$
d_L(F,H)\leq d_L(F,G)+d_L(G,H).
$$

**(2)My question is:** Why do we start with the assumption $d_L(F,G)<\epsilon_1, d_L(G,H)<\epsilon_2$ and why not the same with $\leq$ instead of $<$?
Probably this is some important detail?

Comment: For your first question, see what happens when you take $h=1$ to convince yourself that the distance is at most $1$.

Comment: Great. But my argument is correct, too?

Comment: I don't think so - $F(x-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon > G(x) > F(x+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$ isn't the negation of the inequality in the definition. $h=1$ is a lot more direct, and makes use of the fact that you're dealing with CDFs.

Comment: Of course, your argument is much better, am just interested. Indeed, I was not sure what is the negation of the inequality.

Comment: Generally the reasoning is that $\text{not}(A\cap B)=\text{not}A \cup \text{not}B$ - that is, if the condition is for two inequalities to hold, the negation is for at least one of them *not* to hold.

Comment: Anyway, I use your argument. :)